# psexec command invoking from Windows Service

Tags: c#

I created Windows Service problem which invokes psexec and run .exe in the remote Server. Every thing work fine, when i try to do run in debug mode of invoking pscommand code @ console application, when i try to run pscommand from Windows service, It hangs out without any reason. Is there any reason or alternative.. psexesvc doesnot start on remote server

Here is the pscommand i used

psexec -accepteula \\XYZServer -u  -p  -h \ShareCompName\Component.exe.

There is no error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason for hang state, basically psexec command is calling .exe application, where that exe aplication is performing Admin activity. When PSEXEC command is having -h parameter , then it asking psexec command to execute run as administrator. Since target server where psexec gets executed is having UAC enabling, It is waiting for user input , until user click Yes or NO. application remain in hang state. SO i added extra parameter -i along with -h which automatically takes care of above explained situation.
psexec -accepteula \XYZServer -u -p -h -i \ShareCompName\Component.exe.